# Parse input method key by key in Android?

Tags: android, input, textview, android-edittext, ime

So I have heard that key events are redundant and input methods generally don't trigger them. But I'm just starting to develop a terminal-like app and I want to parse the input key by key, not after "Done"/"Enter" is clicked (for example, for detecting when to insert hard line breaks, just like in commandlines). I use EditText but appending and deleting from TextView is also an option (preferred by me, less combinations with styling and inputtypes).

So the actual question is:
How to listen to input method input key by key? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    }
});
```

or

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Man, I read about onKey one few minutes ago. It seems like I still don't understand these very basic things. So, as keyCode I can define the constant numerical keycode values from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html and define any actions? Great, I'm testing.

Comment: I think the second variant is more preferable to you.
It will allow you to work easy with input. Because all typed text will be in "s" variable. And onTextChanged method will call after all actions (add/remove) with editText

Comment: Worked with a simple Log.v message implying that some actions were done after pressing keys. I will try on it! Thanks.